# How to parse an XML document

Tags: html, xml, function, parsing, dom

I am looking to parse this `.xml` document

```
<instances>
    <courseInstance id="147209" instanceCode="ENGLISH" 
           courseInstanceID="ENGLISH_147209" courseCode="ENGLISH" 
           courseDescription="ENGLISH Program" courseYear="1" 
           startDate="2014-06-01" session="2014" modeOfStudyCode="FULL_TIME" 
           modeOfStudyDescription="Full Time" courseStreamCode="A" 
           courseStreamDescription="Stream A" courseFee="0" waitlist="0" 
           waitlistPlacesLeft="0" instanceStatusCode="PROGRAM_OPEN" 
           instanceStatusDescription="Program Open">
        <service cis="147249" serviceCode="ONLINE_REG" 
                 serviceName="Enroll and Pay" startDate="2016-08-04" 
                 active="1" url="https://xxxx-xxx.xxxx.com/app/xxx/f?p=PV_ONLINE_REG:101:::::APP_COURSE_INSTANCE:147209"/>
    </courseInstance>
<instances>
```

I would like to display it an HTML the page where I list every attribute down a list.

This is the code that I have

```
<h2>Demo</h2>                            
<div id='show_LIVE_LINK'></div>

<script>
    displayCourses(0);

    function displayCourses(i) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               myFunction(xmlhttp, i);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "solar.qll_web.common.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml, i) {
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("instances");

        document.getElementById("show_LIVE_LINK").innerHTML = "courseInstance: " + x[i].getElementsByTagName("courseInstance")
    }
</script>
```

How do I like the attributes one after another vertically going down?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? I do not understand it.

Comment: I have xml that I would like to parse and put into HTML. I have to create a function in my HTML that goes through the XML tree, but I dont know how to create the function that can extract all the attributes such is 'id' in a list on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Element nodes have an `attributes` collection:

```js
var xml = `<instances>
    <courseInstance id="147209" instanceCode="ENGLISH" 
           courseInstanceID="ENGLISH_147209" courseCode="ENGLISH" 
           courseDescription="ENGLISH Program" courseYear="1" 
           startDate="2014-06-01" session="2014" modeOfStudyCode="FULL_TIME" 
           modeOfStudyDescription="Full Time" courseStreamCode="A" 
           courseStreamDescription="Stream A" courseFee="0" waitlist="0" 
           waitlistPlacesLeft="0" instanceStatusCode="PROGRAM_OPEN" 
           instanceStatusDescription="Program Open"/>
</instances>`;

var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

function display(xmlDoc, index, targetEl) {
  targetEl.textContent = '';
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  [].forEach.call(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('courseInstance')[index].attributes, function(att) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = att.name + ' : ' + att.value;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    });
  targetEl.appendChild(ul);
}

display(xmlDoc, 0, document.getElementById('result'));
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Obviously instead of parsing a string of XML with DOMParser you want to use the responseXML of an XMLHttpRequest but once you have that you can read out the attributes of an element as shown.